# How do you remove the exponential text in axis values in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels, qutip

On the x-axis, my units are in ns as this is what the physics dictates. However, I don't want the exponential text highlighted to be seen.

[image]

Is there anyway this can be removed while keeping the x-axis units the same?

One further question is with regards to sharing the x-axis between the two plots. I want the residual plot on the bottom to be connected to the top while resizing the y-axis.

Previously I set the hspace of the subplots to be 0 but this makes the y-axis values overlap. Are there any solutions to this?

I'd like to point out also that I'm using QuTiP if anyone has expertise in this then that'd be greatly appreciated. I'm sure it should be easy enough to convert the code into a QuTiP style either way.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Multiply your x data by 1e9, so that you actually plot nanoseconds.